# conda update not working - package version remains same under conda list

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update the `pandas` library to the latest version, but conda doesn't seem to be doing so. I ran the following line

`conda update pandas`

and this is the output I got back

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

However, it doesn't appear to have updated since the version still isn't working in my Jupyter Notebook. I've also tested for this by running the command

`conda list | grep "pandas"`

and received this output

`pandas                    0.23.4`

So clearly, it's not being updated for some reason. I even tested with `pip3` which gave me an installed version of `0.25.3` so I'm not really sure why this is happening and I have a project that's due soon, so I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: @AMC there was no environment created during this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a fix. For some reason, it appears there was a conflict between `pip / pip3` and `conda` that was causing `conda` to keep referencing the old `pandas` version. It might also be because `pandas` relies on other packages, which haven't been updated since the last command required me to update `numpy` and other packages for the command to be executed efficiently.

Anyways, here's the set of commands I ran to fix the issue:

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip3 uninstall pandas
conda install pandas=0.25.3
```

Comment: just curious, did you install pandas originally using pip/pip3? when using conda, best practice is to install using conda and if that fails, then use pip. Using both can cause this and other issues, but sometimes is unavoidable.

Comment: @DonaldStierman Yup, I think that's what was happening. The notebook given to me as an assignment was doing installs in both conda and pip and the matplotlib one was done through pip, and I think that was definitely the cause of the issue.